# Multi git repo fast data mining API

Tags: git, gerrit, opengrok

Is there a system which allows fast API access to the complete version history and any version of any file in any out of several hundred git repos.
The git CLI is way too slow. Gerrit is even slower.

I am basically looking for something which can automatically mirror a large number of git repos, but store the data in a more efficient way so that it can be quickly accessed via some API.
Read a bit about OpenGrok, but its API does not seem to make detailed version history available. It is more focused on searching.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in giving this a try [using hadoop.](http://blogs.wandisco.com/2013/09/17/git-data-mining-with-hadoop/)

Still seems pretty experimental, but it's a short read and might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your second paragraph is correct; OpenGrok allows you to search

- File contents
- Commit log contents

but does not allow you to search the contents of *historical* versions of a file. There is a chance that, using pre-commit hooks, you can enforce structured commit messages and thus make this a workable solution going forward.

I apologize for not being able to answer your question, but hopefully this narrows down your search.